# Find mismatch location across two vectors, including NAs

Tags: r, vector, match

I'm quite embarrassed to ask this question. An experienced R user should definitely know this, yet here goes:

I need to find the location of the mismatches between two supposedly identical vectors. It's very important in this case that NAs are considered mismatches.

### Data example

```
> x <- c(1, NA, NA, NA, 5); x
[1]  1 NA NA NA  5
> y <- c(1, NA, NA, 4, 5); y
[1]  1 NA NA  4  5
```

### What I want to get

Doesn't matter to me if I get a boolean vector or a numeric vector with the mismatch locations:

```
> c(F, T, T, T, F)
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
> 2:4
[1] 2 3 4
```

### Things I've tried:

```
> which(x != y)
integer(0)
> setdiff(x, y)
numeric(0)
> !(x %in% y)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use :

```
x != y | is.na(x & y)
#Or checking NA individually
#x != y | is.na(x) | is.na(y)
#[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

You can then easily wrap `which` around this to get numeric vector

```
which(x != y | is.na(x & y))
#[1] 2 3 4
```

Comment: Thanks. But, actually, I asked the wrong question (my bad, not yours). I wanted NAs to be considered mismatches only if they were not in the same position across vectors. I was nonetheless able to come up with a solution, based on your answer:

> # Correct data example
> x <- c(1, NA, NA, 4, 5)
> y <- c(1, NA, 3, NA, 6)
> # Output I'm actually looking for:
> c(F, F, T, T, T)
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
> 3:5
[1] 3 4 5
> # Solutions, based on your answer:
> !(x %in% y & y %in% x)
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
> which(!(x %in% y & y %in% x))
[1] 3 4 5
>

Comment: Actually, the example above is terrible, because, as I discovered through trying and error, "%in%" checks for matches anywhere in the two objects, not only in the same position. This is a much better example: 
x <- c(1, NA, 2, 3, NA); x
y <- c(1, NA, NA, 2, 3); y

Solution I found:
which(x != y | ((is.na(x) & !is.na(y)) | (is.na(y) & !is.na(x))))

Not perfect, but at least I can get the location of the mismatches.

Comment: @LucasDeAbreuMaia Ohh...I see. For the updated case, I would have solved it in the similar way.